# F# Interactive - how to make it print properties of an object, when the latter is enumerable

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

It's easier to show on example. If I send the following to F# interactive

```
type Person = {Name : string; Age : int}
let joe = {Name = "Joe"; Age=30}
```

The output is:

```
type Person =
  {Name: string;
   Age: int;}
val joe : Person = {Name = "Joe";
                    Age = 30;}
```

Fsi is smart enough to print all the properties.

Sending the following, line-by-line

```
let l = new List<int>()
l
```

results in

```
val l : List<int>
val it : List<int> = seq []
```

Fsi sees that `l` implements `IEnumerable`, and (rightfully) thinks this is what I expect to see.  But there are other properties in `l`, notably `Count` and `Capacity`. (That's not that important for lists, but it is for complex types in my case)

*How do I make F# interactive print out the properties of an object and ignore it being `IEnumerable`?* (just like for the type `Person` in the first example)

Answer (score 8):

You can provide a custom printer using `fsi.AddPrinter`. It takes a function that specifies how to format a specific type - I don't think there is an easy way to do this generically, but you can use non-generic `IEnumerable` in this case. The following prints the sequence using the default printing and adds `Count`:

```
fsi.AddPrinter(fun (en:System.Collections.IEnumerable) -> 
  let count = Seq.cast<obj> en |> Seq.length
  sprintf "%A { Count = %d }" en count
)
```

For example:

```
> l;;
val it : List<int> = seq [] { Count = 0 }
> seq { 1 .. 100000 };;
val it : seq<int> = seq [1; 2; 3; 4; ...] { Count = 100000 }
```

Funnily enough, this also changes printing for strings, but you could avoid that by adding the custom properties only when `en` value is not of type string.

```
> "hello";;
val it : string = "hello" { Count = 5 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you override the `.ToString` method, fsi will use that instead. You can also use the 
`[<StructuredFormatDisplay>]` attribute if only want to affect FSI